# Duda con una consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql

como bien dice el titulo es una duda porque no estoy seguro de que pueda hacerse, pero bueno, ahí va:

Pongamos que hago una join de dos tablas, una tiene anuncios (spots) y la otra bloques de anuncios, la consulta queda así:

```
SELECT Blocs.Numbloc, Spots.Nom FROM Blocs, Spots WHERE Blocs.Spot=Spots.ID
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

Entonces, mi duda es la siguiente:

Hay alguna forma (con una consulta SQL) de que me devuelva todos los nombres de cada "numero de bloque" en una fila, añadiendo una ',' por cada nombre?

Ejemplo:

Ahora está así:

```
Numbloc |    Nom
_______     _____

6       |    Non Massa Non Company

6       |    Arcu LLP

6       |    Augue Corporation
```

Y me gustaria que quedara así:

```
Numbloc |    Nom
_______     _____

6       |    Non Massa Non Company, Arcu LLP, Augue Corporation
```

Saludos y muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar la función `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT Blocs.Numbloc, GROUP_CONCAT(Spots.Nom)
  FROM Blocs, Spots 
 WHERE Blocs.Spot=Spots.ID
GROUP BY Blocs.Numbloc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b736d/1/0

Mas info sobre [GROUP_CONCAT](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlfun=GROUP_CONCAT)

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias!!